# C# asp web.config location autorization deny for whole folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

When i set this code in web.config

```
<location path="Pages">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <deny users="?" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
```

it deny access for other folder as "UC" folder

I was trying this

```
<location path="UC">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="*" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
```

and it didnt give me access

What to do? I try giving path other source but it didnt work. Please help me with this code

Answer (score 0):

I find it is most simple to add a web.config file for each folder you want to secure. That way, you don't have to go wandering though and messing with the root web.config of which we all know is a nasty jungle of markup.

So, for each folder, simple add a web.config to secure that folder.

So, say I have a site admin folder, then I'll have this:

[image]

And inside of that web config, I have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
            <allow roles="SiteAdmin" />
            <deny users="*" />
        </authorization>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

So, now, for each folder, I have a simple, clean, and easy to read + maintain security settings for any aspx page in that folder.

In most cases, the root of the site does not require a logon, but sub folders for various things like the site administrator of course needs to be secured by role membership. So, I recommend that for each folder you wish to secure, you add a web config following the above format.